# Simple domain objects attribute values

Tags: oop, dns, domain-driven-design, ooad

Let's say you've got a domain model class for a Song. Song's have a tempo attribute (an int) that should always be a positive number. Should this requirement be part of the domain model or externally (such as in a SongManager / business logic layer class)?

Let's say you've chosen to implement it like so:

```
class Song {
  private int tempo;
  // ...

  public void setTempo(int tempo) {
    if (tempo > 0) {
      this.tempo = tempo;
    } else {
      // what?
    }

  }

}
```

Would you replace `// what?` above with:

1. Nothing. Given a Song instance `s`, `s.setTempo(-10)` would simply not modify the object's state.
2. Set tempo to some minimum value, eg `1`.
3. Mark `setTempo` with a *checked* `throws InvalidTempoException` and `throw` it in the `else` clause. That way, a controller or other component is responsible for catching the invalid tempo value and making a decision about how to handle the exception.
4. Throw a *runtime* InvalidTempoException.
5. Extract the tempo attribute into a Tempo class with the "must be greater than 0" encapsulated there.
6. Something else.

I ask because I've been exploring the common "layered architecture" approach lately and in particular the domain layer.

Comment: Although the smell of #3 is obvious (having to catch or duck the checked exception of every `setTempo` call) is there a way to leverage that such that the ducked exception essentially "bubbles up" to some validation layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `Song` is not valid with a zero or negative tempo value, this certainly should be an invariant modelled within `Song`.

You should throw an exception if an invalid value is attempted - this makes certain you don't have a `Song` in invalid state.

Comment: @ybakos - I am answering in a language independent manner, as you didn't tag your question with a specific language. From your comment I surmise you are asking about a Java implementation. I don't have an answer for that specific language. However, this is something that would happen at _runtime_ when the attribute exists and might be modified.

Answer (score 2):

> Song's have a tempo attribute (an int) that should always be a
>   positive number

If this is a requirement for the proper initialization of the `Song` then you should throw a corresponding exception e.g. `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: In Java the IllegalArgumentException is a runtime exception. I understand that this is sound (that's the intent of IllegalArgumentException) but why not throw a checked exception instead to ensure that it's caught?

Comment: This shouldn't be caught. If the `Song` should have a specific invariant in order to be considered as initialized properly then this should be a runtime exception

Answer (score 2):

> Should this requirement be part of the domain model or externally (such as in a SongManager / business logic layer class)?

Domain related logic should live in domain model. Calling something as Manager often is a sign that you just don't know where to put code and how to name it properly.

> Nothing. Given a Song instance s, s.setTempo(-10) would simply not modify the object's state.

In case you need **trying** to set tempo and if you have little control over argument that is going to be passed, ignoring failure to set tempo can be acceptable. It's like with UDP protocol - it's fine if it fails. Only I would name it accordingly - something like s.trySetTempo(-10).

> Set tempo to some minimum value, eg 1.

That is like extension of first case. Only I can't think of any business case when there would be a need to default song tempo to near zero.

> Mark setTempo with a checked throws InvalidTempoException and throw it in the else clause. That way, a controller or other component is responsible for catching the invalid tempo value and making a decision about how to handle the exception.
>   Throw a runtime InvalidTempoException.

Throwing an exception means that anything that tries to set tempo is responsible for proper input because there should never be expected exceptions. Usually you would also have to write canSetTempo (or something like isTempoChangeable) indicator method so outside world could hit it before trying real deal.

> Extract the tempo attribute into a Tempo class with the "must be greater than 0" encapsulated there.

This depends on shape of your domain. It might be a good idea if anything else (like SoundSample class, MidiClip class) needs to use concept of tempo. Also - it might be good to encapsulate tempo if it is almost unrelated to your business and just polluting more interesting logic in Song class.

---

I personally like when domain model provides an answer if action is available but action itself throws an error. That allows to make better UX too. Fields and buttons that are responsible for changing tempo would just not appear/be disabled - an immediate feedback that something can't be done just yet.

Comment: Another flaw with checked exceptions: any method that invokes `setTempo` is pained with catching or ducking the exception.

Comment: @ybakos i find that untrue. exceptions should not happen. if they do - it's enough with one global handler.